# Change the "emoji" content of the button upon clicking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm making a button for the theme in the website. I want to change the content of the button upon clicking, switching between  and . But it's not working. What's wrong?

I have made a button.

```
 <div class="sticky-btn">
    <button id = "theme-btn"></button>
  </div>
```

Here's the CSS class:

```
.sticky-btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's my JS:

```
let themeBtn = document.getElementById("theme-btn");
const clickBtn(){
  if (themeBtn.textContent === "") {
    themeBtn.textContent = "";
  }
  else {
    themeBtn.textContent = "";
  }
}
themeBtn.addEventListener("click",clickBtn)
```

Comment: `const clickBtn(){` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

The function 'clickBtn' is not properly defined.
You can use:

**Function declaration**: `function clickBtn() {}`

**Function expression**: `const clickBtn = function() {}`

or

**Arrow function**: `const clickBtn = () => {}`